# How to find files with the same filename (except what's inside parenthesis) and deleting the smaller size ones

Tags: file, ubuntu, terminal, find, command

I need to know how to find one or more files with the same filename (except what's inside parenthesis) and delete the one(s) with the smaller size, in a folder. I don't care if it's a GUI app or terminal command.

Example: Addams Family, The (USA) / Addams Family, The (World) / Addams Family, The (Europe) (En,Fr,De)

I've already learned how to find duplicate files using *find -type f -print0 |     awk -F/ 'BEGIN { RS="\0" } { n=$NF } k[n]==1 { print p[n]; } k[n] { print $0 } { p[n]=$0; k[n]++ }'*, although I don't really understand the awk in question. What I need is to isolate the smaller duplicates and delete them.